# How to read csv into sparkR ver 1.4?

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

As a new version of `spark` (1.4) was released there appeared to be a nice frontend interfeace to `spark` from `R` package named `sparkR`. On the [documentation page of R for spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) there is a command that enables to read `json` files as an RDD objects

```
people <- read.df(sqlContext, "./examples/src/main/resources/people.json", "json")
```

I am trying to read a data from a `.csv` file like it is described on [this revolutionanalitics' blog](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/06/sparkr-announcement.html)

```
# Download the nyc flights dataset as a CSV from https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sparkr-data/nycflights13.csv

# Launch SparkR using 
# ./bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3

# The SparkSQL context should already be created for you as sqlContext
sqlContext
# Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext id 1

# Load the flights CSV file using `read.df`. Note that we use the CSV reader Spark package here.
flights <- read.df(sqlContext, "./nycflights13.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

The note says I need a spark-csv package to enable this operation. So I downloaded this package from this [github repo](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) with this command:

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

But then I encountered such error while trying to read a `.csv` file.

```
> flights <- read.df(sqlContext, "./nycflights13.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
15/07/03 12:52:41 ERROR RBackendHandler: load on 1 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:36)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ddl.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:1230)
    ... 25 more
Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE
```

Any idea on what this error means and how to solve this?

Of course I could try to read `.csv` in a standard way such as:

```
read.table("data.csv") -> flights
```

and then I can transform R `data.frame` into `spark`'s `DataFrame` like this:

```
flightsDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, flights)
```

But this isn't the way I like it and it is really time consuming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to start sparkR console each time like this:

```
sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Rstudio:

```
 library(SparkR)
 Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3" "sparkr-shell"')
 sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

does the trick. Make sure the version you specify for spark-csv matches the one you downloaded.

Comment: Do you know if this can be passed to sparkR.init with sparkJars parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you install sparkr from within spark using:

```
install.packages("C:/spark/R/lib/sparkr.zip", repos = NULL)
```

and not fro github

that solved it for me.

Comment: I had a proper installation of Spark ver 1.4 but coud not load spark csv data, as at that time the additional package was needed. The solution was written here a year ago, so please don't spam http://stackoverflow.com/a/31206855/3857701